# Comparar dos listas y eliminar repetidos

Tags: java

Tengo dos listas de string

1. listA = {a,b,c}
2. listB = {e,a,b,d,c}

Quiero tener una sola lista con todos los elementos sin ninguno repetido,

Ejemplo: `listFinal = {a,b,c,d,e},`

Lo he logrado haciendo esto:

```
 listB.removeAll(listA);
    listA.addAll(listB);
```

Pero me gustaría hacerlo sin esas funciones, algo de recursividad acaso cómo sería el código?

Comment: Por que recursividad? A veces las soluciones más complejas no son las mejores. De hecho mientras más simple puedas hacerlo mejor. Si es porque has tratado con algún código recursivo y no ha funcionado, publicalo para verlo y ver que puede estar incorrecto. Si no, puedo proponerte una manera iterativa aceptable.

Comment: Goku, como comenta lealceldeiro "A veces las soluciones más complejas no son las mejores", pero esto depende de que "performance" requieres en tu aplicación. Es bueno agregar lo que trataste y comentar para que lo usarías! :D

Answer (score 2):

Una forma sería convertir los `array` a `List`, concatenarlos y eliminar elementos repetidos en `listFinal`, mediante este método:

```
//elimina duplicados.
List<String> listFinal = Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
                     .distinct()
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

El procedimiento completo sería:

```
String[] listA = {"a","b","c"};
String[] listB = {"e","a","b","d","c"};

//Convierte a List ambos arreglos        
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(listA));
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(listB));

//Concatena listas.       
List<String> listFinal = Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
                     .distinct()
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());

//Ordena lista
Collections.sort(listFinal);        


//al final obtienes una lista que no incluye elementos repetidos
listFinal.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Salida:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes combinar las dos listas en un `HashSet`. En ese caso, se eliminarán los duplicados y los elementos quedarán ordenados sin ninguna manipulación adicional.

Código de ejemplo:

```
    List<String> listA = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("z","a", "b", "c"));
    List<String> listB = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("e","a", "b", "z", "c", "d"));
    Set<String> setCombined = new HashSet<>(listA);
    setCombined.addAll(listB);
    System.out.println(setCombined);
    List<String> listCombined = new ArrayList<>(setCombined);
    System.out.println(listCombined);
```

Aquí, tanto en `setCombined` como en `listCombined` tendrás tus elementos sin duplicados y ordenados, puedes usar cualquiera de los dos para presentar los datos según tus requerimientos.

La salida por pantalla es esta:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, z]
[a, b, c, d, e, z]
```

Aquí, puedes ver una <kbd>**[DEMOSTRACIÓN EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/MQKA49921)**</kbd>