# ¿Cómo comparar elementos de 2 ArrayList para eliminar un elemento que ya se encuentra dentro del otro?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Quiero saber como se hace la comparación de los elementos que hay dentro de dos ArrayList, independientemente del tamaño de alguno de ellos, ejemplo

PrimerArray={1,2,3,4}
SegundoArray={1,3}

y si se valida que hay un elemento que existe dentro del otro que se elimine de alguno de ellos.

Ya en la practica real el problema surge porque quiero que de una consulta a una tabla de Sql no muestre los elementos dentro de un combobox que ya existen o fueron seleccionados en otro combobox.

```
    public ArrayList IDComun = new ArrayList();//variables globales
    public ArrayList IDComunDEADministrador = new ArrayList();


    public ArrayList Aux = new ArrayList();//pense en usarlo pero es igual no pude hacer que me sirviera de mucha ayuda


    public void mostrarIDCOmun()//metodo para la consulta a la tabla
    {

        conexion.Open();

        string sqlComunicacion = $"select * from Comunicacion";
        SqlCommand comandoComun = new SqlCommand(sqlComunicacion, conexion);
        SqlDataReader registroComun = comandoComun.ExecuteReader();



        while (registroComun.Read())
        {
            IDComun.Add(registroComun.GetInt32(0).ToString());
        }
```

En esta parte de abajo está el problema ya que he probado de varias formas los ciclos anidados y solo he logrado que se repitan los elementos en el combobox o que genere un error de indice fuera de rangpo al ser un ArrayList con más elementos que el otro

```
for(int y=0;y< IDComunDEADministrador.Count;y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < IDComun.Count; x++)
            {
                //for (int y = 0; y < IDComun.Count; y++)
                //{
                if (IDComun[y] == IDComunDEADministrador[x])
                {
                    IDComun.RemoveAt(y);
                }

                //}
            }
        }

  

        cmbIDComunicacion.DataSource = IDComun;

        registroComun.Close();


        conexion.Close();


    }
```

De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda, estaré al pendiente.

Saludos.

Comment: Creo que tienes la respuesta en ésta otra pregunta contestada con anterioridad:

[Respuesta eliminar comunes en arrayList](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/189336/comparar-dos-listas-y-eliminar-repetidos)

Comment: ¿Los ArrayList que tipo de dato contiene?  Son ArrayList<Integer>?

Comment: Hola Moisés, me puedes decir si la respuesta dada te resultó útil, gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para obtener los elementos del arreglo que están en **A** pero no están en **B** puedes usar el **operador de conjunto Except** de **Linq**.

Si **A** tuviera los elementos **A**(**1**, **2**, **3**, **4**) y **B**(**1**, **3**, **5**):

```
var x = A.Except(B);
```

**x** devolvería una lista con estos elementos **x**(**2**, **4**).

Y para saber los que están en **B** pero no están en **A** haríamos:

```
var y = B.Except(A);
```

y devolvería una lista con estos elementos **y**(**5**).

Para usar el **operador Except** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```